# Auto update status column based on due date column in mysql database

Tags: mysql

Ok so I have a `varchar` status column and a `date` due_date column in a mysql database.

I am wanting to know what to do to make the mysql database update the status column to Overdue when the date in the due_date column passes the current date.

Is this something that is possible right in php my admin?

I am looking for advice on where to head on this situation. I am admitting I have no clue how to approach this problem. Feel free to link to other questions, external website, or just put your own opinions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `users` SET `status`='Overdue' WHERE `due_date` > CURDATE();
```

You can use this query directly in phpMyAdmin if you want to update it once. Or you can write a cron that runs once every day and updates the records.

Comment: This is changing the rows where the due_date has not passed yet. I tried flipping > to < and it still changed the same ones :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `TRIGGER`. please see the following link on how to create triggers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html